# Access variables javascript/jquery

Tags: jquery

I have the following code

```
$('#first').click(function() {
    myVar = $(this).next().val();
});

$('#second').blur(function() {
    console.log(myVar);
});
```

How to access myVar within #second ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It depends on the wider context of your code. You can do this:

```
(function() {
    var myVar;

    $('#first').click(function() {
        myVar = $(this).next().val();
    });

    $('#second').blur(function() {
        console.log(myVar);
    });
})();
```

That creates an anonymous function and calls it right away. The purpose of the anonymous function is to provide a container for `myVar` *without* making `myVar` a global variable. Global variables are generally best avoided (not least because they become properties of the `window` object, which already has all sorts of junk stuck on it). Specifically, the functions you're assigning to your `click` and `blur` events become *closures* over the data inside the call to the anonymous function. They have access to `myVar`, but nothing else does. [More here](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2008/02/closures-are-not-complicated.html).

If your code is already inside a containing scope, or you don't care about adding to the global namespace, you don't need the anonymous function.

Comment: +1. Correct answer. I have no idea why everyone is doing `(function(){})()` instead of `(function(){}())`. The latter seems much more natural to me. The outer parenthesis are not needed either, but they signalize something secial going on.

Comment: @elusive: why not ask a question here as to why ;-)

Comment: @elusive: Because (I'm told) there's an ambiguity in the grammar that makes just `function(){}();` unreliable. The parens around the function expression are required in some edge cases. This doesn't apply to just using a function expression or even to accessing its properties (`function(){}.call(...);` works just fine, for instance), it has to do with the parens triggering the call. Example: http://jsbin.com/ecuba3 On Chrome, that fails with an "unexpected token" error. Add the parens and it works: http://jsbin.com/ecuba3/2 (Actually, given how simple that is, maybe it's not an "ambiguity".)

Comment: @T.J. Crowder: Right, the outer parenthesis are required. I did not know that. `(function(){}())` works as expected. I perfer this method and i discovered that Doug Crockford writes his code like this, as well.

Comment: @elusive: Cool that there are two ways to do it. I prefer the parens just around the function, to me it more clearly indicates what I'm doing, but it's horses for courses.

Answer (score 2):

Define myVar in the outer scope:

```
var myVar;

$('#first').click(function() {
    myVar = $(this).next().val();
});

$('#second').blur(function() {
    console.log(myVar);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

T.J. Crowder's answer does what you want. This is just an alternative (using the jQuery [data storage](http://api.jquery.com/data/) methods):

```
$('#first').click(function() {
    // Assign this element to have data with the key 'myVar'
    $(this).data('myVar', $(this).next().val());
});

$('#second').blur(function() {
    // Read the data from the other element
    console.log($('#first').data('myVar'));
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The answers here are good. But I think you're at the point where you'd benefit from reading [Crockford's JS slideshow](http://www.scribd.com/doc/41582808/Javascript-Crock-Ford). It's very good and explains several matters related to your question.